# Equation of curve satisfying the given condition

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A curve passing through the origin is such that the middle point of the segment between a point and intersection point on x-axis of its normal lies on the parabola $2y^2=x.$ Find the equation of the curve.

Using all the given conditions, I have reached

$y^2=2x+y \frac{dy}{dx}$ but I am not able to solve this differential equation. Could someone help me this?

Comment: $y\,{\mathrm{d}y \over \mathrm{d}x} = {1 \over 2}\,{\mathrm{d}\left(\, y^{2}\, \right) \over \mathrm{d}x}$.

Comment: @ mathgeek Is the edit ok? Else please feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\mrm{y}^{2}\pars{x} & = 2x + \mrm{y}\pars{x}\,\totald{\mrm{y}\pars{x}}{x}
\quad\imp\quad
\totald{\mrm{y}^{2}\pars{x}}{x} - 2\mrm{y}^{2}\pars{x} = -4x
\\[5mm]
\totald{\bracks{\expo{-2x}\,\mrm{y}^{2}\pars{x}}}{x} & = -4x\expo{-2x}
\quad\imp\quad
\expo{-2x}\,\mrm{y}^{2}\pars{x} = C - 4\int x\expo{-2x}\,\dd x
\\ C & :\ \mbox{Integration Constant}. 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The parabola $ y^2 = 2 a x + b $ has the property of constant sub-normal ( projection of normal on x-axis = $ y y^{\prime} = a $.

In the present case  for given midpoint parabola by differentiation $  y y^{\prime} = \frac14 $

So you need a bigger parabola   $  y y^{\prime} = \frac12 $ of double the length of normal.

Integrating, $ y^2 = x  + C $

$C=0$ to pass through the origin.

However if both parabolas have to pass through the origin there is a *problem with the given problem...* as seen in the plots  $ y^2 = x,\, y^2 = x/2 $ below.

[image: Parabolas]